# Issues with progress tracking - AFNetworking queue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have the following code for downloading two request using AFNetwork queue

```
NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray array];
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL1];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request1];
operation1.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:PATH1 append:NO];

[operation1 setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    float progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    NSLog(@"Progress 1 = %f",progress);
}];
[operations addObject:operation1];

NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL2];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request2];
operation2.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:PATH2 append:NO];

[operation2 setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    float progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    NSLog(@"Progress 2 = %f",progress*100);
}];
[operations addObject:operation2];
```

Adding requests to `AFTHTTPClient`

```
AFHTTPClient *requestHandler = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:BASEURL];

[requestHandler enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    NSLog(@"%d completed on %d",numberOfCompletedOperations,totalNumberOfOperations);

} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
}];
```

The problem is I get the progresses separate for each request. But I need the progress as a whole for both the requests combined.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a global float to control this, and the total of all progress is:

TotalProgress = firstProgress/numOperations + secondProgress/numOperations

```
//Declare this like a global.
#define numOperation 2    
float globalProgress = 0.0f;



//Your Operation Instances:
NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray array];
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL1];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request1];
operation1.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:PATH1 append:NO];

[operation1 setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    globalProgress += ((float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead)/numOperation;
}];
[operations addObject:operation1];

NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL2];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request2];
operation2.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:PATH2 append:NO];

[operation2 setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    globalProgress += ((float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead)/numOperation;
}];
[operations addObject:operation2];
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: No. It gives the wrong progress. But i changes your code to make it work. I added two global variable and store each progress and it really works.